# DeMorgan's laws

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I need some help understanding DeMorgan's Law. I have read my discrete math textbook, and looked up the formula sheet my hardware professor handed us, but still find myself struggling with it. We have a circuit we have to build converting it all to NAND gates using DeMorgan's law.

Now, if anyone can explain DeMorgan's law better to me, that would be awesome. My formula I am working on is:

> W’Y’+W’Z+W’X’+WXY

Please do not provide me with the full answer, but if you want to provide me with the first step, that would be awesome.

Thank you,
KeiU

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a circuit with NAND gates, you have to have a SOP expression. Then you can complement your expression twice as below :

```
((W’Y’+W’Z+W’X’+WXY)')' = 
((W’Y’)'.(W’Z)'.(W’X’)'.(WXY)')'
```

so you have 5 NAND gate for the expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a conceptual understanding of DeMorgan's Laws:

$P \land Q$ says that both $P$ and $Q$ are true

$P \lor Q$ says that at least one of $P$ and $Q$ is true

OK, so the DeMorgan's Laws are:

$\neg(P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor \neg Q$

$\neg(P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \land \neg Q$

So, to explain them:

$\neg(P \land Q)$ is true iff

$P \land Q$ is not true iff

not both $P$ and $Q$ are true iff

at least one of $P$ and $Q$ is not true iff

at least one of $\neg P$ and $\neg Q$ is true iff

$\neg P \lor \neg Q$

Likewise:

$\neg(P \lor Q)$ is true iff

$P \lor Q$ is not true iff

not at least one of $P$ and $Q$ are true iff

both $P$ and $Q$ are not true iff

both $\neg P$ and $\neg Q$ are true iff

$\neg P \land \neg Q$

Hope that helps ...